# Why "try " is not allowed in naming convention of a package in java

Tags: java

I tried creating a package with name resources.try, resources.try.com, resources.com.try in eclipse but it continuously giving me an error "Invalid package name. 'try' is not a valid Java identifier"

Is there any specific reason that we shouldn't use "try" in naming a package?

Comment: You can't use Java keywords in package names, or any other identifier (variable, class etc.)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Comment: try is a reserved keyword. (try-catch)

Comment: Other than the fact that it's a keyword? This might be enough, since you do need to write it down in an `import` or `package` line.

Comment: ***if the package name begins with a digit or other character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name, or if the package name contains a reserved Java keyword, such as "int"***

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is reserved word used in `try { ... } catch {}` statement.

You can't use reserved word as identifier.

Answer (score 2):

For the simple reason that `try` is a java keyword

See this link for other reserved keywords 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to google your queries a bit. If you are satisfied with an answer please accept it as the solution!